# A D3js collapsible force layout with directed paths?

Tags: graph, svg, d3.js

I am trying to do a force-directed layout in which the links are arrows pointing to nodes (as in the examples shown [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1153292) and [here](http://www.d3noob.org/2013/03/d3js-force-directed-graph-example-basic.html))  and also in which the nodes that have children are collapsible  (as shown in Mike Bostock's examples: [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130)  or [here](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html)).

So far collapsing the nodes works fine, but I'm having trouble understanding how the arrow heads are included in the paths.  Here is part of my code, based on the examples above:

```
force.nodes(nodes)
    .links(links)
    .gravity(0.05)
    .charge(-1500)
    .linkDistance(100)
    .friction(0.5)
    .linkStrength(function(l, i) {return 1 })
    .size([w, h])
    .start();

 // Append markers
 vis.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
    .data(["end"])
  .enter().append("svg:marker")
    .attr("id", String)
    .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
    .attr("refX", 15)
    .attr("refY", -1.5)
    .attr("markerWidth", 6)
    .attr("markerHeight", 6)
    .attr("orient", "auto")
 //.append("svg:path")      // <-- I not sure what this does
  //.attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");


var path = vis.selectAll("path")
    .data(force.links());


// Enter new paths
path.enter().insert("svg:path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
    .style("stroke", "#ccc");


// Exit any old paths.
path.exit().remove();


// Update the nodes…
var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; })

node.select("circle")
    .style("fill", color);

// Enter any new nodes.
var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("svg:g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
    .on("click", click)
    .call(force.drag);


//Add an immage to the node
nodeEnter.append("svg:image")
      .attr("xlink:href",  function(d) { return d.image;})
      .attr("x", function(d) { return (0 - Math.sqrt(d.size)) / 10 || 4.5;})
      .attr("y", function(d) { return (0 - Math.sqrt(d.size)) / 10 || 4.5;})
      .attr("height", 16)
      .attr("width", 16);


// Exit any old nodes.
node.exit().remove();

// Re-select for update.
node = vis.selectAll("g.node");
path = vis.selectAll("path")

force.on("tick", function() {
     // Draw curved links
     path.attr("d", function(d) {
    var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    return "M" + d.source.x + "," 
            + d.source.y 
            + "A" + dr + "," 
            + dr + " 0 0,1 " 
            + d.target.x + "," 
            + d.target.y;
     });

     node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
});
```

What I understand is that the piece of code below is responsible for drawing the arrow heads, by specifying a block where the arrows should be pointing to (e.g. `.data(["end"])`)

```
 vis.append("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
     .data(["end"])
   .enter().append("svg:marker")
     .attr("id", String)
     .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 10 10")
     .attr("refX", 15)
     .attr("refY", -1.5)
     .attr("markerWidth", 6)
     .attr("markerHeight", 6)
     .attr("orient", "auto")
   .append("svg:path")      
     .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");
```

This is then referenced when the path is entered (i.e. `.attr("marker-end", "url(#end)");`).

But I might be missing something, because in my graph the paths are shown, but not the arrows.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Good question! Gosh I struggled with those arrow heads. I'm looking forward to seeing what turns up here.

Comment: The `path` you append in the SVG marker definition is responsible for drawing the actual arrow. Did you run your code with that commented out (first code block)?

Comment: Thanks @LarsKotthoff, I figured that out right after I posted the question. It didn't work before when it was uncommented, and since I didn't understand what it did I commented it out. Writing `path.link` almost fixed it. I put my answer below. However, there's still a little something that prevents it from working completely fine...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that is "almost" working. Here is the complete code, and short explanation of what is still  failing at the bottom:

```
    var w = 1280,
        h = 800,
        root,
                    vis;

    var force = d3.layout.force()
                .gravity(200)
                .charge(-1500)
                .linkDistance(100)
                .friction(0.01)
                .size([w, h])
                ;


    $(document).ready(function() {

        var newHeight = '100%';

        $("#svgdiv").html("<svg id='graph' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='100%' height='100%'></svg>");

        vis = d3.select("svg");

        d3.json("../json/flare.json", function(json) {
            root = json;
            root.fixed = true;
            root.x = w / 2;
            root.y = h / 2;


        // Build the arrow
        var defs = vis.insert("svg:defs").selectAll("marker")
            .data(["end"]);

          defs.enter().append("svg:marker")
            .attr("id", String)
            .attr("viewBox", "0 -5 15 15")
            .attr("refX", 15)
            .attr("refY", -1.5)
            .attr("markerWidth", 6)
            .attr("markerHeight", 6)
            .attr("orient", "auto")
          .append("svg:path")
            .attr("d", "M0,-5L10,0L0,5");       

            update();
        });
    });



    /**
     * 
     */
    function update() {
      var nodes = flatten(root),
          links = d3.layout.tree().links(nodes);

      // Restart the force layout.
      force.nodes(nodes)
            .links(links)
            .gravity(0.05)
            .charge(-1500)
            .linkDistance(100)
            .friction(0.5)
            .linkStrength(function(l, i) {return 1 })
            .size([w, h])
            .start();


        var path = vis.selectAll("path.link") // <-- THIS WAS CHANGED TO "path.links"
            .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });

          path.enter().insert("svg:path")
            .attr("class", "link")
            .attr("marker-end", "url(#end)")
            .style("stroke", "#ccc");


      // Exit any old paths.
      path.exit().remove();


      // Update the nodes…
      var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
          .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id; });

      // Enter any new nodes.
      var nodeEnter = node.enter().insert("svg:g")
          .attr("class", "node")
          .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
          .on("click", click)
          .call(force.drag);


        node.select("circle")
          .style("fill", color);


      nodeEnter.append("svg:circle")
          .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
          .style("fill", color);

      // Add text to the node (as defined by the json file) 
      nodeEnter.append("svg:text")
          .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
          .attr("dx", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
          .attr("dy", ".35em")
          .text(function(d) { return d.name; });
      /* */

      //Add an image to the node
      nodeEnter.append("svg:image")
              .attr("xlink:href",  function(d) { return d.logo;})
              .attr("x", function(d) { return (0 - Math.sqrt(d.size)) / 10 || 4.5;})
              .attr("y", function(d) { return (0 - Math.sqrt(d.size)) / 10 || 4.5;})
              .attr("height", 16)
              .attr("width", 16);
       /* */    


      // Exit any old nodes.
      node.exit().remove();

      // Re-select for update.
      node = vis.selectAll("g.node");
      path = vis.selectAll("path.link");   // <-- THIS WAS CHANGED TO "path.link"


      force.on("tick", function() {


        path.attr("d", function(d) {
            var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
                dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
                dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy); 
            return  "M" + d.source.x + "," 
                        + d.source.y 
                        + "A" + dr + "," 
                        + dr + " 0 0,1 " 
                        + d.target.x + "," 
                        + d.target.y;
        });


        node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

      });

    }


    // Color leaf nodes orange, and packages white or blue.
    function color(d) {
      return d._children ? "#3182bd" : d.children ? "#c6dbef" : "#fd8d3c";
    }

    // Toggle children on click.
    function click(d) {
      if (d.children) {
        d._children = d.children;
        d.children = null;
      } else {
        d.children = d._children;
        d._children = null;
      }

      update();
    }



    // Returns a list of all nodes under the root.
    function flatten(root) {
      var nodes = []; 
      var i = 0;

      function recurse(node) {
        if (node.children) 
            node.children.forEach(recurse);
        if (!node.id) 
            node.id = ++i;
        nodes.push(node);
      }

      recurse(root);
      return nodes;
    }
```

I think one of the reasons that the arrows didn't show was that I gave a class to the path, as in `path.enter().insert("svg:path").attr("class", "link")`,  but i didn't reference it correctly when the path was being selected and therefore it didn't draw it
(i.e. I had:

```
  var path = vis.selectAll("path")
```

where it should've been:

```
  var path = vis.selectAll("path.link").)
```

Then I also found out that the defs for the arrow head markers should be defined outside the update() function, which is called when collapsing and expanding the nodes. Otherwise, it appends it to the svg everytime you click on a node, and this is not very effective.

So now the nodes collapse onclick and the arrows are drawn (although they are ugly). However, there's still one problem that gets me very confused:  after a while, without any apparent time interval or click pattern, the graph freezes and debugging in the browser says that `Cannot read property 'target' of undefined`. This error is triggered on the "tick" function, where the curved path is being defined:

```
    path.attr("d", function(d) {
        var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
            dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
            dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy); 
        return  "M" + d.source.x + "," 
                    + d.source.y 
                    + "A" + dr + "," 
                    + dr + " 0 0,1 " 
                    + d.target.x + "," 
                    + d.target.y;
    });
```

It doesn't find  `d.target` because the path variable is reinitiated (like this `path = vis.selectAll("path.link");` )  before entering `force.on("tick", function() ...`

The strange thing is that it works at the beginning and it suddenly might stop working after a random while! 
So does any body have any idea of what might be going on??

EDIT:

I now know what was wrong. For some reason I was using a script d3.layout.js that I found somewhere, which I thought was needed for the collapsing of the tree. I removed that library and used the normal d3.v3.js and everything works like it should... just that the arrows are ugly.  So, the script above should work, having collapsible nodes and directed paths.

Comment: I created a gist to show a live example: [http://bl.ocks.org/djjupa/5653692](http://bl.ocks.org/djjupa/5653692)