# How to link extra attributes from json data in a D3.js force layout?

Tags: javascript, json, graph, d3.js, force-layout

I have followed the various examples from [Mike Bostock](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock) to create a collapsible force  layout with directed paths and images at the nodes (related to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16383764/a-d3js-collapsible-force-layout-with-directed-paths)).

Now, I want to link some extra information to some of the nodes if they contain any extra information, as structured by the data in a json string.

The json string that looks like this:

```
 {
   "name": "Somename",
   "text": "Some text",
   "extradata": [
            {
              "type": "sometype",
              "icon": "someicon.png"
            },
            {
               "type": "sometype02",
              "icon":  "someicon.png"
            }
   ],
   "children": [
    {
        "name": "Somename",
        "text": "Some text",
        "extradata": [
            {
              "type": "sometype",
              "icon": "someicon.png"
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "Somename",
        "text": "Some text",
        "extradata": [
            {
              "type": "sometype",
              "icon": "someicon.png"
            },
            { .... },
            { .... },
            { .... },
            ....
        ],
        "children": [
        {
            ....
        }
    },
    ........
```

In short, I would like to display some of the values of  the `extradata[]`  array linked to every node that this extradata attribute. The end result would look something like the image below, where the blue circles represent the contents from extradata (e.g  `sometype` or `sometype02`).

[image]

I'm having trouble understanding how to parse the json string in order to get to those values, and how to create the links to the nodes where they belong.

Answer (score 1):

The beauty of d3 is that the Javascript objects are intrinsically linked to the DOM objects that represent them. You might even say the data *drives* the document.

Presumably you have something like this:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(data.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    [...]
```

Maybe you want to color each node according to the first `datatype` property in the JSON:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(data.nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .style("fill", function(d) { 
        return d.extradata[0].type === "sometype" ? "#FF0000" : "#0000FF";
    })
```

Point is, you already have access to the object in the `d` variable passed to the function.

Here's an [example](http://news.yahoo.com/those-who-liked-r--kelly-also-like-international-hernia-awareness-day--white-house-petitions-as-a-social-network-050307279.html) of using the FDL and coloring nodes from a data property. Also includes tooltips.

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks for your answer and your example, but Im still confused! What I want to do is simply display the elements of extradata as additional nodes that link to their parent (so in the picture above, the two blue circles would be "sometype" and "sometype02"). I almost manage to achieve it by going through the Nested Selection tutorial again and looking through examples. Basically, i parse through the elements of extradata by using `.each` and treat each element as a new node. However, I cannot get the position and `force` right, so all those new nodes sit on top of each other...